# How to redirect from the main domain to a subdomain in Cloudron?

Tags: redirect, docker

I have a [Cloudron.io](https://cloudron.io/) app under the `www.domain.tld` location.

I wan't the main domain `domain.tld` to redirect to `www.domain.tld`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I was able to follow the steps given about setting up a redirection in Cloudron. In fact, I decided to write a full article about it to help others understand how to fix this issue step by step.
You will have to make sure you put the right DNS entries and then set up the redirection. [Read this guide](https://ugacomp.com/how-can-i-fix-cloudron-domain-redirection-issues/) here and it will help you to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to redirect from a container to another with a simple Apache redirect.

Use the "LAMP"-app or [built your own](https://cloudron.io/tutorials/packaging.html#basic-app).